# Can an array index get value from other array index in the same array

Tags: php, arrays

The question is "can an array index get value from other array index in the same array?" Such as when you have an array variable like this:

```
$conf = [
  "app" => [
    "name" => "myApplicationName",
    "key" => md5($conf['app']['name']) // I mean to call itsself
    // I tried using $this but return into error

  ]
]
```

When I write `$conf['app']['name']` it returns the error:

> Undefined variable: conf in..

So can I call or get value to an array index from other array index in the same array?

Comment: FYI, your English wasn't a problem, the formatting with bold, italic and quotes where not necessary made it hard to read

Comment: okay, thanks for the guide

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've seen, because of the way PHP parses the array for definition, that syntax does not work.  You can define them separately:

```
$conf["app"]["name"] = "myApplicationName";
$conf["app"]["key"]  = md5($conf['app']['name']);
```

Or define the large array and add it:

```
$conf = [
  "app" => [
    "name" => "myApplicationName",
    "something" => "something"
    //add more keys etc...
  ]
];
$conf["app"]["key"] = md5($conf['app']['name']);
```